# Не понимаю в чем проблема?

Tags: java, javafx

Класс Main:

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
     controllerCreateNewBuildMods = new ControllerCreateNewBuildMods();
     System.out.println("   Program start!");
     System.out.println("");

    storageVariables = new StorageVariables();

    language=storageVariables.getLanguage();

    while (aBoolean == true){
        try{
            icons.add(new Image(getClass().getResource("res//icons//" + i + ".png").toString()));
            i++;
        }catch(Exception e){
            i--;
            System.err.println(" *Найдено " + i + " иконки");
            amount = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(amount);
    controllerCreateNewBuildMods.setAmount(amount);//Здесь важно

    fXMLLoader_MainMenu = new FXMLLoader();
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainChoiceTheBuildMenu.fxml"));
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.Properties.MainMenu", new Locale(language)));

    Parent panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainChoiceTheBuildMenu.fxml"));
    Scene scene=new Scene(panel,700,500);
    stageMainMenu=new Stage();
    stageMainMenu.setScene(scene);

    stageMainMenu.setTitle(fXMLLoader_MainMenu.getResources().getString("key_MainMenu_Title")); //titleMainMenu
    stageMainMenu.show();

}
```

Класс ControllerCreateNewBuildMods:

```
@FXML
ImageView imgCreateNewBuildModsIconBuildMods;

private int amount;
private int position = 1;
private String stringLanguage;

private Main main = new Main();
private StorageVariables storageVariables=new StorageVariables();
private Image img;


public void setAmount(int amount){
    this.amount = amount;
    System.out.println(amount);//Здесь выводит 135(Так и должно быть)
    System.out.println(this.amount);//Здесь выводит 135(Так и должно быть)
}


// Инициализация GUI компонентов класса 'CreateNewBuildMods' под текущий язык

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    amount = main.getAmount();

    img = new Image(getClass().getResource("res//icons//"+position+".png").toString());
    stringLanguage=storageVariables.getLanguage();
    ResourceBundle lngBndl = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("sample.Properties.MainMenu", new Locale(stringLanguage));
    imgCreateNewBuildModsIconBuildMods.setImage(img);
}


/*
    Методы - контроллеры для кнопки 'btnBackImage'
 */
// Этот метод - контроллер кнопки 'btnBackImage' обрабатывает нажатие кнопки
public void inquiryQuestionBtnBackImage() {
    if(position == 1){

    }
    position = amount;
    System.out.println(position); //Здесь выводит 0, хотя должен 135
    img = new Image(getClass().getResource("res//icons//"+position+".png").toString());//Здесь выдает ошибку, так - как нет файла 0
    imgCreateNewBuildModsIconBuildMods.setImage(img);

}
```

Не понимаю почему такая фигня. Подскажите пожалуйста. Я новичок

Comment: А где же тот самый код кнопки? Можно взглянуть на сие действие?

Comment: Описание кнопки в fxml файле. Суть, как мне кажется не в этом. Я на самом деле не понимаю, почему сначала переменная amount хранила 135, а потом стала хранить 0

Comment: Метод inquiryQuestionBtnBackImage обрабатывает нажатие на эту кнопку

Comment: вы не там что-то делаете. Как минимум у контроллера можно вызвать метод `public void initialize()` в котором описать инициализацию, в том числе и установить `amount`, т.е. в контроллере писать `public void initialize() {
        amount = 135;
    }`

Comment: Это число получается в результате вот этого кода:  while (aBoolean == true){
        try{
            icons.add(new Image(getClass().getResource("res//icons//" + i + ".png").toString()));
            i++;
        }catch(Exception e){
            i--;
            System.err.println(" *Найдено " + i + " иконки");
            amount = i;
            break;
        }
    } И может меняться, из - за чего я не могу так сделать

Comment: ДА лааааадно, Этого нельзя сделать в контроллере? ..Врете вы все)))......хм........ тогда нужно чуть по другому к контроллеру обратиться... написал это в ответе ... обратите внимание на `controllerCreateNewBuildMods = fXMLLoader_MainMenu.getController();
    controllerCreateNewBuildMods.setAmount(666);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `new ControllerCreateNewBuildMods();` - вы создаете совсем другой экземпляр контроллера. Совсем не тот, к которому "обращается" кнопка при нажатии

Вы можете попробовать обратиться к контроллеру из `FXMLLoader` и сделать необходимое.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("foo.fxml").openStream());
FooController fooController = (FooController) fxmlLoader.getController();
```

Конкретно в вашем код в `Main` будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {    
    // Здесь какие-то действия, вам необходимые

    // ...

    fXMLLoader_MainMenu = new FXMLLoader();
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainChoiceTheBuildMenu.fxml"));
    fXMLLoader_MainMenu.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.Properties.MainMenu", new Locale(language)));

   //Это не нужно! ->>>> Parent panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainChoiceTheBuildMenu.fxml"));
    Parent panel = (Parent) fXMLLoader_MainMenu.load();

    // А здесь обращаемся к контроллеру и делаем наши дела
    controllerCreateNewBuildMods = fXMLLoader_MainMenu.getController();
    controllerCreateNewBuildMods.setAmount(666);

    // Инициализируем "Сцену"
    Scene scene = new Scene(panel,700,500);
    stageMainMenu = new Stage();
    stageMainMenu.setScene(scene);

    stageMainMenu.setTitle(fXMLLoader_MainMenu.getResources().getString("key_MainMenu_Title")); //titleMainMenu
    stageMainMenu.show();

}
```

---

Но вообще инициализацию лучше сделать там, где нужно. Например непосредственно в нужном контроллере, либо сделать главный `MainController` и сделать всю необходимую инициализацию там. Как это делается?

Есть такой метод как `initialize`. Он запускается в контроллере автоматически (если он там присутствует) при инициализации соответственно. Можно там всё и сконфигурировать.

Например объявляем в `controllerCreateNewBuildMods` метод:

```
public void initialize() { 
    // do smth
}
```